# Cannot receive image url from this async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am trying to get the image url from itunes. 
This is the code:

```
interface SongProps {
  data: {
    name: string;
    artist: string;
    album: string;
    at: string;
  };
}

const ITUNES_ENDPOINT =
  "https://itunes.apple.com/search?limit=1&&media=music&limit=1&term=";
async function artWork(name:string, artist:string): Promise<string | null> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (name.length === 0) {
      resolve(null);
      return
    }
    const searchTerm = `${artist} ${name ? name : artist}`;
    fetch(`${ITUNES_ENDPOINT}${encodeURI(searchTerm)}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.results.length > 0) {
          const res = data.results[0];
          resolve(res.artworkUrl100.replace("100x100", "600x600"));
        }
        resolve(null)
        return null
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error("Critical failure: " + e.message));
  });
}

const src = (props:SongProps)=>{
  return [
  artWork(props.data.name,props.data.artist)
]
};
const FinalImg = (props:{src:string | number})=>{
  console.log(src)
  return (
              <View style={styles.albumArtContainer}>
              <Image source={src} style={styles.albumArt} />
            </View>
  )
}
```

and my result in `src` shout be `src=
  "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music30/v4/a0/08/ee/a008eecc-f4e8-4eec-e293-95aed1673a54/source/100x100bb.jpg";` 
I got no errors.
Any advice?
P.S.: I am a newbie in ts

Comment: JavaScript executes synchronously before returning to the event loop. `async` functions return a promise for a value returned in the future (after network traffic, data base lookup etc.). So `artwork` returns a promise, and `src` is set to an array containing a promise. Is this what the `console.log` call is showing?

Comment: In the console i receive: [[Function src]

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.]
I tried to put the a [await] method but it received it as an var